# Ocelot API Gateway error: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: c#, api, microservices, api-gateway, ocelot

I am trying to build a microservice architecture system using Ocelot as my API Gateway.  I have had the current problem for about 2 weeks and have not been able to figure out why it is happening, so I am turing to the experts and hopefully you can help :).

The structure at the moment is as follows: I have an AccountAPI and an Ocelot API Gateway.  I have added the route from the API Gateway to the AccountAPI according to the docs.  When I run the project, I can call the AccountAPI directly, and it works fine. But when I call through the API Gateway, I get this error.

```
Error Code: ConnectionToDownstreamServiceError Message: Error connecting to downstream service, exception: 
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. 
(localhost:5101)
```

Quite obviously, it is not even reaching the controller of the AccountAPI, so I can't even debug >.>

The fact that I can access the object without going through the gateway tells me it is not a network / firewall issue (I turned off all my firewalls just to test, and got the same result).

This is what is in my ocelot.json file (which should connect Ocelot to the AccountAPI)

```
{
  "GlobalConfiguration": {
    "BaseUrl": "http://localhost:5111/"
  },
  "Routes": [
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/Account/{url}",
      "DownstreamScheme": "http",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 5101
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/MeHealth/Account/{url}",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE" ],
      "Priority": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

So if I call `https:// localhost:5101/Account/1`  I get my correct object returned.  But with calling `https:// localhost:5111/MeHalth/Account/1` I get the error. (I did also try `http://` (for those who caught the scheme) and I get the same result as https)).

Other things to note:  Both of these are deployed through the docker-compose with the following config:

```
services:
    ocelotapigateway:
        environment:
            - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
            - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
        ports:
            - "5111:443"
        volumes:
            - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:C:\Users\ContainerUser\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\UserSecrets:ro
            - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:C:\Users\ContainerUser\AppData\Roaming\ASP.NET\Https:ro

    accountapi:
        environment:
            - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
            - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
        ports:
            - "5101:443"
        volumes:
            - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:C:\Users\ContainerUser\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\UserSecrets:ro
            - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:C:\Users\ContainerUser\AppData\Roaming\ASP.NET\Https:ro
```

Any advice or help that you can give will be greatly appreciated. Please also let me know if you need extra information on something.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is `localhost` on your host machine is not same as `localhost` when running in docker container. Think about docker as isolated "virtual machine" with its own `localhost`. When your api gateway tries to reach `localhost:5101` it fails because it not exists in this "virtual machine", it's running on your host machine. You have 2 solutions here:

1. Use `host.docker.internal` and external port instead of `localhost`: `https://host.docker.internal:5101`.
2. When running 2 containers under same non-default docker network (that's what happens when you run docker-compose) they can reach each other by service name and internal port: `https://accountapi:443`

Comment: I am also facing the same problem, running  gateway and api  through docker compose and not able to connect each other and receiving 502 bad gateway. Have you resolve this?

Comment: @SaadAwan did you try either of the options in this answer?

Comment: Yes I tried both option but sam result with different error

Comment: Please check my answer , as I am not able to give much details in comments section so please check my answer in which  I show my ocelot and docker_compose file and tried 2 options mentioned by you. @lydse should you able to resolve your issue?

Comment: After spent some 12 hours and with @Artur inputs finally I am able to connect my api with apigateway. the only small thing just need to consider in mind that commented out app.UseHttpsRedirection(); in API startup.cs file

Answer (score 1):

Do not use https (and remove app.UseHttpsRedirection())

Use docker internal host name:  "Host": "host.docker.internal"

Below is working example;

Ocelot.json

```
{
  "Routes": [
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/v1/{everything}",
      "DownstreamScheme": "http",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "host.docker.internal",
          "Port": 7001
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/article-service/{everything}",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE" ]
    },
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/v1/{everything}",
      "DownstreamScheme": "http",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "host.docker.internal",
          "Port": 7002
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/review-service/{everything}",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE" ]
    }
  ],

  "GlobalConfiguration": {
    "BaseUrl": "http://localhost:7000"
  }
}
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  data: 
    container_name: sqlserver
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
    environment: 
      - SA_PASSWORD=@P****
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
    ports:
        - "1433:1433"
    volumes:
        - ./APPDATA:/var/opt/mssql/data 

  myapp.apigateway:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}myappapigateway
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: MyApp.ApiGateway/Dockerfile
    ports:
    - "7000:80"

  myapp.articleservice:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}myapparticleservice
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: MyApp.ArticleService/Dockerfile
    ports:
    - "7001:80"

  myapp.reviewservice:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}myappreviewservice
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: MyApp.ReviewService/Dockerfile
    ports:
    - "7002:80"
```

**docker-compose.override.yml**

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  myapp.apigateway:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
    ports:
      - "80"
      - "443"
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
      - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro

  myapp.reviewservice:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
    ports:
      - "80"
      - "443"
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
      - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro

  myapp.articleservice:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
    ports:
      - "80"
      - "443"
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
      - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro
```

Answer (score 0):

I also trapped in the same problem just only need to commented out in API's startup file

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
```

and in ocelot file

```
 "Host": "host.docker.internal",
 "Port": 5101
```

**OR**

```
 "Host": "service-name",
 "Port": 80
```